# Bash grep: /dir/dir/myconfig./config No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

All the directories are there and correct. I triple-checked twice. I am a little bit confused about it but I am sure I didn't make a mistake anywhere. It might be a permission issue and I really need to get this to work so I am thinking of just getting Linux since that might get the whole process easier.
app.py

```
import subprocess

class httpRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path in ["/date", "/time"]:
            self.path = "static" + self.path + ".html"
            return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
        elif self.path == "/":
            self.path = "static/index.html"
            return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

conf = subprocess.run(["grep", "port=", "/dir/dir/myconfig.config"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

port = conf.stdout.split(b"=")[1]

socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
server = socketserver.TCPServer(("", int(port)), httpRequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

myconfig.config

```
port=8000
```

```
python3 app.py

/dir/dir/myconfig.config: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to change the grep to cmd and also Powershell. The code is 100% correct and I believe this to be a permission issue. Any ideas?

Comment: This might happen if `/dir/dir/myconfig.config` is a dangling symlink.

Comment: I am on Windows so I don't think that might have happened. Its a normal config file .

Comment: If you are on windows the directories paths use backslashes (\\) instead of / (as in Linux or MacOS). To me, the error you are getting is correct. Have you tried using the full path of the file, like C:\\\\directory\\file_name?
Or you could try to `cd` where your `myconfig.config` file is, modify this part
`conf = subprocess.run(["grep", "port=", "/dir/dir/myconfig.config"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` to `conf = subprocess.run(["grep", "port=", "myconfig.config"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` , re-run script and check if you still get the error. If not, it's due to how you wrote the absolute path.

Comment: Moving the file to the same depository as the app has helped! I honestly don't know how that didn't occur It probably had something to do with the backslashes but I didn't test that theory. Thank you very much!!!!!! It really helped a lot.